# What's the meaning of (*DefaultHandler)(nil) where DefaultHandler is a struct?

Tags: go

I can understand whole last line of code meaning: It provides a static (compile time) check that `*DefaultHandler` satisfies the `EasygateHandler` interface. But I cannot understand what's the meaning of `(*DefaultHandler)(nil)` and what's the difference with `(*DefaultHandler)()`

```
type DefaultHandler struct {
    log logrus.FieldLogger
    svc *service.DefaultResolver
}

var _ easygate.EasygateHandler = (*DefaultHandler)(nil)
```

Comment: The expression `(*DefaultHandler)()` is not valid Go code.

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes. It makes sense to use `&DefaultHandler{}`, what's the syntax of (*DefaultHandler)(nil)?

Comment: The expression `(*DefaultHandler)(nil)` is a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) from the untyped nil to a nil value of type `*DefaultHandler`.  The value `&DefaultHandler{}` can also be used if default handler is a type with composite literal syntax.  The conversion pattern works for all types.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I wonder if this question isn't really a dupe of the other one. Sounds like @Jacky understands the blank identifier part (which was the point of the other question), and is more asking about the `(*DefaultHandler)(nil)` syntax.

Comment: 100% Duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(*DefaultHandler)(nil)` is a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) from an untyped nil to a zero value of type `*DefaultHandler`.

Conversions are of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and `x` is a value that can be converted to type `T`. In this example, `T` is `*DefaultHandler` and `x` is `nil`.   The parenthesis around `*DefaultHandler` are required to distinguish the conversion to a pointer type from a dereference of a a conversion to the non-pointer type.

The expression `(*DefaultHandler)()` is not valid Go syntax.

The value `&DefaultHandler{}` can also be used if `DefaultHandler` is a type with composite literal syntax. The conversion pattern works for all types.

Comment: However, in general `&SomeType{}` will allocate and initialise a new value (unless the compiler detects and optimises it out) where-as `(*SomeType)(nil)` will never do any allocation.